# Total possible outcomes when duplicate values are present

Tags: probability

Consider a triangular dice with four sides, the value on each side is 4, 4, 8, 10 respectively (yes two sides have the same value 4).
Now, what is the total number of possible outcomes when I roll the dice? Is it 4 or 3? Do we count or ignore duplicate values?

Comment: The possible outcomes are $\{4,8,10\}$ with probabilities $\{\frac 12,\frac 14, \frac 14\}$.

Comment: It depends on what you consider to be "a possible outcome". If you consider the two sides to be indistinguishable, (i.e., you only care about the resulting number), then there are three possible outcomes. If the die is fair, the event in which the outcome is $4$ takes place with probability $\frac{2}{4}$, the other two events each with probability $\frac{1}{4}$. If the two sides are distinguishable (e.g., have different colors), then you might consider four unique events, each occurring with probability $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Depends how "outcome" is defined. Number? Then $3$ outcomes.

Comment: Please do note and remember that probability of occurrence is not going to be the ratio of "number of good outcomes" over "total number of outcomes" in situations where the outcomes are not equally likely to occur.  As alluded to earlier, assuming the die is fairly weighted, these don't each occur with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ just like how in a lottery you either win or you lose but winning doesn't occur with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: For the purpose of working with a sample space where outcomes are equally likely to occur, I would choose to temporarily imagine each side to have a unique identifier, just like how with a marbles in a bag scenario I might imagine each marble is numbered so that I can tell them apart.  A bag with 20 marbles, three of which are red, but otherwise marbles are indistinguishable might have only two outcomes for me drawing a marble, either red or not red, but by imagining numbers on the marbles suddenly I have twenty equally likely outcomes, three of which correspond to red giving probability 3/20.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to upvote, otherwise I would have done that to every comment.